# Setting Visible in PageLoad

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am running Visual Studio 2015 community, and I am experiencing some severe weirdness.

I have a page with a form the goes something like this:

```
<form>
    <label...>
    <textbox....>
    <label...>
    <textbox....>
    ....
    <label...>
    <textbox....>
    <asp:Button ID="Sbutton1" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" CssClass="CSubmitRight" />
    <asp:Button ID="Sbutton2" runat="server" Text="Go Back" CssClass="CSubmitRight" OnClientClick="JavaScript: history.go(-2); return false;" />
</form>
```

Now the problem is that when I try on page load or load complete to set the visibility of the buttons with a simple SButton1.visible = true and then try to run the page in debug mode, I get a message that there are build errors.  When I comment out the visibility line, no problems running the code. I have no errors or warnings in the Error List.

I have tried restarting VS as that sometimes fixes annoying issues.  I have tried putting them in Panels and setting the visibility of the panels, and I get the same error.  I tried putting them in div's and then calling a JS function to change the display property of the div from On Page Load, but it doesn't change the visibility of the divs.

Why am I getting a compile error?  Any clues?

Comment: Can you show us the Page Load code?

Comment: Show an example of the errors.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub _Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ButtonBlock1.Visible=true
    ButtonBlock2.Visible=false
    If IsPostBack then
        UpdateBatch()
        ButtonBlock1.Visible=false
        ButtonBlock2.Visible=true
    Else
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "SQL SELECT CRAP"
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim ds As DataSet = new DataSet()
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(ds)

        selScanUser.DataSource = ds
        selScanUser.DataValueField = "ID"
        selScanUser.DataTextField = "UserName"
        selScanUser.DataBind()
        conn.Close()
        cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd.Connection.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And if I comment the visibility statements out, compile the page, run it, uncomment the visibility statements, reload the page, it works as intended.  It just will not compile while those statements are there

Comment: Please edit code into your question, do not post it as a solution unless it actually answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

May be you have syntax error. Asp controls have a property "Visible", so that should work. Check whether you have typo or matching case. In C# "visible" and "Visible" both are different.

```
SButton1.Visible = true;
```

or please post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: If you do not have enough information to make an informed guess about what the problem is, then do not answer. Wait until you know.

Comment: I can confirm that the it gives me the same error using true and "true".  I am just getting a message that there were build errors, do I want to  continue and run....  When I "Build" the website, I finally get an error in the error windows stating that the button is not defined or inaccessible due to protection level.  !!?? Hmmmm  it lets me interact with all the controls before the buttons just fine.